# How to stop phone charging from battery when laptop is unplugged

Tags: laptop, phone, charging

Sometimes I plug my phone in to my laptop for USB tethering (bluetooth tethering works terribly for some reason so this is not an option), but annoyingly it charges from my laptop battery when the (android) phone is plugged into my laptop. How do I stop this from happening when my laptop is unplugged (from charging it's own battery).

Comment: There are ways to power off a USB device, but these options most probably cut off the data too. Physically modifying a USB cable to cut the power line (so only GND DATA+ DATA-) results in not even noticing there is a USB device connected. There could be some hacks to make the host device (Laptop) detect a USB device is plugged, but this could result in the client device (Phone) not recognized being plugged to the computer.

Comment: how does this relate to ask ubuntu?

Comment: Since this question is not specific to Ubuntu, I would recommend asking this in one of these: [general Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [general Computer](https://superuser.com/), for modifications/hacking about USB cables [general electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @24601 perhaps there was a setting somewhere in the ubuntu settings? Since I can't find any info about this anywhere its hard to know

Comment: Im not aware of any such setting

Comment: Setting in the bios?